# Can not install SAM CLI on mac os

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to follow instructions mentioned in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/sam-cli-requirements.html#sam-cli-requirements-cli) to setup my first Amazon Lambda -based app. However when I type "pip install aws-sam-cli" I get the following error :
"Collecting aws-sam-cli
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement aws-sam-cli
  No distributions at all found for aws-sam-cli"

I am using python 2.7.10.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with python versions. I had an corrupted old version of python 2.7 ... I installed 3.6 but it did not work. So I deleted and uninstalled EVERYTHING related to pythons and installed 2.7 from scratch.After that I was able to install SAM cli smoothly without any problem.

So conclusion , make sure your python is working properly and is up-to-date. Make sure you do not have version conflicts.